# What kind of circular 16 pin connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

[image: Mystery connector]

This is a connector on some device.  I need to build an adapter which goes between the shown parts.  Is this some kind of "standard" connector?  I see 16 pins. The device is from the US.  The connection is digital/serial at 3.3V level.

Comment: Please [edit] to include some dimensions. "The device is from the US." Why not tell us the make, model and purpose of the device?

Comment: I cannot disclose make, model or purpose.  But the device may be used in environmentally very harsh conditions, so it is very rugged. I'll add dimensions as soon as I can (in about 24h)

Comment: Looks like a connector from Lemo. [This might be the one.](https://www.lemo.com/en/products/low-voltage-connector/e-connector)

Comment: Well, I mean. It's an American 16-pin connector; there's many of these. Information on its application are somewhere between extremely helpful to necessary to solve this riddle. Your inability to disperse critical information doesn't make the information less critical – so, VTC as unclear. (also: Free help. If you need free help for a commercial project, you'll have to get all the clearances to ask.)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a MIL spec connector. Big manufacturers are Amphenol, Deutsch and LEMO. There are hundreds upon hundreds of connectors in that spec, so I wish you good luck finding the correct one.